# Chain promises when rendering template

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, es6-promise

**Function that fetches data.**

Get a connection and fetch some data. Omitted some code.

```
function executeSQL(sql, bindParams , options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ...
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

**Controller that uses that function**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

    database.executeSQL('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL', [] , {})

    .then(function(result) {
      res.render('index' , { TITLE : 'Lorem Ipsum Blog' });
    })

    .catch(function(err) {
      next(err);
    });
};
```

My `index` controller is used in my `index` route.

I'll need to call my executeSQL function at least twice. Only after both of them are done do I want to call `res.render` and send in my data that I fetched.

How do I chain them?
Do I even need to chain them? Can I just execute them asynchronically and once they're both done then I call `res.render`.

Comment: How about `Promise.all(arr).then` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre When I run console.log on on result1 it returns undefined. My render function is not getting the results from those 2 promises.

Comment: My Bad... Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/Lson6f62/1/

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks, do you want to post that as you answer?

Comment: I will not mind so if this helped!

Comment: Ok , do it then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), *The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved.*

```js
function executeSQL(sql, bindParams, options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(result);
  });
}
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  var pro1 = database.executeSQL('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL', [], {});
  var pro2 = database.executeSQL('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL', [], {});
  Promise.all([pro1, pro2]).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); //result will be an array
    res.render('index', {
      TITLE: 'Lorem Ipsum Blog'
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    next(err);
  });
};
```